# Counter: pulse every 8 clocks

Tags: pic, clock, atmel, attiny, counter

I have a square signal (fixed but can be between 12MHz and up to 48MHz) and I would like to create every 8 clocks a pulse as brief as possible, no more than 1/4 of the period.

[image: Pulse every 8 clocks]

First, a couple of loose constraints:
- voltage is at 1.8V but I could have a shift level up to 5V if needed.
- I need the pulse every 8 times, but I would be fine with every 16 or every 32 times.

The key objective is to have the most SIMPLEST approach. Please avoid any answer suggesting a teraflop super computer!

Similarly, FPGA would really make sense but it's like killing a mosquito with a bazouka.

One option consists of using an Atmel 8-bit chip such as AtTiny85 but it's limited to 20MHz so I'm not sure if it could really work or not.

I have read this page with great interest: http://ued.udjat.nl/counter/ and I'm wondering if I could use a similar stratagem.

I prefer AtTiny because of the small package, then Atmel, then Cypress, then Microchip but I'm listening for any option. Is there any option to do something without a "micro processor"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this problem with just a couple of parts. TI makes logic parts in their 74AC logic family that operate correctly down to 1.5V. Use a 4 bit counter as shown below to repeatedly count from 8 to 15. Use the RCO output, which is a one clock wide pulse to reload the counter and to also drive an R/C circuit to produce the narrow pulse that you require.

[image]

If you desire to produce the pulse for every 16 input cycles then just connect the D input to GND instead of being pulled up to the VCC rail.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, then what you want could be achieved using a simple counter IC and a couple of logic gates. You could use a similar strategy to the linked project.

For example, something like this [4-bit, 200MHz binary counter](http://uk.farnell.com/nxp/74lvc163pw-tssop16/ic-logic-4-bit-binary-counter-tssop16/dp/2132711) (or a similar chip) could be used with a couple of gates to check for every x111 state (i.e. 0111 and 1111) which happens every 8 cycles. The brief pulse can be created with an RC high pass filter to create the desired edge and another gate to square it up.

Of course many micros with a capture/compare peripheral would be suitable for this - off the top of my head I think the PIC16F1828 would probably be suitable. There are many faster options such as PIC32, Cortex-Mx, etc, but what to go for would depend on how much the uC would be used. You are right it would be overkill to use e.g. an FPGA or Cortex-M4 just for this task.

A more suitable IC might be the popular [4017 decade counter](http://uk.farnell.com/texas-instruments/cd74hc4017m/logic-decade-countr-divider-16soic/dp/1739754). With this you would not need any other chips (apart from the pulse shortening bit), you can set it to divide by N (i.e. divide by 2,3,4,5,6,7,8...) by simply connecting the appropriate output to the reset pin. Here are a few pages with info:

[All About Circuits](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_6/chpt_7/6.html)
[4017 Datasheet](http://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/fn32/fn3297.pdf)
[Doctronics 4017 page](http://www.doctronics.co.uk/4017.htm)

Answer (score 1):

A CPLD like an XC2C32 from Xilinx would be perfect.

- Like an FPGA but much less complicated and powerful
- Can run at up to 300MHz
- 1.8V operation
- Cheap (less than $2)